# Change the style of an input when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3vz45os8/7/

I've got this jsfiddle where I want to change the background color of the input text in a specific color if the word is well type and in another one if the word is not well type. It's currently doesn't work but I got no error in the console. If u guys could help me.

This is the js function, I log every step and didn't get an error:

```
function isCorrect() {
  var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
  if (test.value === "hello") {
    test.classname = "correct"
    return true;
  } else {
    test.classname = "incorrect"
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: May I know why you accepted the other answer while mine being the first one?

Comment: there were actually 3 errors, the last one was correct in the jsfiddle that he post, it was concerning  the css but I upvote ur answer

Comment: Thanks @mel. What's the third error?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, the CSS wasn't working properly. Also, the code sample you posted would not work. You removed the wrong .value call, it should have been removed from the declaration, not the if statement.

Comment: @Brandon, What's the difference between removing it from the if statement and in the declaration? Both does the same right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, no. If you remove it from the declaration, then you're declaring that `test` is equal to the element itself and **not** the string value of the input. If it's the element, then the rest of the code (checking the value and adding the className) is valid. If it's the string value, then it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
if (test.value === "hello") {
```

You're calling `.value` twice. Take it off the first line, because otherwise you'll be adding `className` (which should be camel-cased by the way) to a string value instead of the input element.

Here is the corrected code and a [working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/3vz45os8/6/):

```
function isCorrect() {
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    if (test.value === "hello") {
        test.className = "correct";
        return true;
    } else {
        test.className = "incorrect";
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's correctly adding the class, but your CSS is being overridden so I just removed the default color for illustration.

Answer (score 2):

You're doubling up on values:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
                                          ^^^^^^
if (test.value === "hello") {
        ^^^^^^
```

`test` is ALREADY the value of that input, which means it's a plain string. A string has no `.value` attribute, so you're doing `undefined === "hello"`.

```
Also use className not classname
              ^             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have a few errors:**

1. The keyword is `className` not `classname`. Please change that.
2. You are already getting the `.value`. No need to call it again.

**Corrected Code:**

```
function isCorrect() {
  var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
  if (test === "hello") {
    test.className = "correct"
//------------^
    return true;
  } else {
    test.className = "incorrect"
//------------^
    return false;
  }
}
```